# What book contains the rules for creating travelling shows?

Tags: product-identification, books, rifts, palladium-system

I noticed that the Palladium website has a [Traveling Show Creation Log](http://www.palladium-megaverse.com/cuttingroom/Official/Rifts/Travelling_Show_Log.pdf). Presumably this worksheet would be used while working through the rules, detailed in a supplement of some kind, for defining a traveling show and its membership. In which book can I find the rules for traveling show creation?

Answer (score 6):

### Learn how to create your own traveling shows from *Rifts World Book 1: The Vampire Kingdoms*

Traveling shows are given a lengthy description in *Vampire Kingdoms* for reasons I've never really understood. I mean, it seems like the absolute last region you'd want an open-air traveling circus—where most folks will be attending after work *when it's dark* and where workers wear scary costumes—is in an area infested with *vampires* (at least, if you weren't one, I guess), but so it goes. They're in there, traveling shows are, in all their wonky glory, on pages 117-28.

I'm using original [*Vampire Kingdoms*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0916211525) (1991) page numbers. I don't own the more recent [*Vampire Kingdoms Expanded*](http://palladium-store.com/1001/product/802-E-Rifts-Vampire-Kingdoms-Expanded-and-Updated.html) nor [*Rifts Vampires*](https://palladium-store.com/1001/product/884-Rifts-Vampires-Sourcebook.html), but neither lists *Build your own creepy traveling shows!* as a selling point.

Answer (score 1):

The [*Rifts Adventure Guide*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1574570722) contains rules, tables, and a walk-through for creating a travelling show on pages 142-155, as does [*Vampire Kingdoms*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0916211525) on pages 117-139. There's also a PDF somewhere on the Internet that contains a printable checklist that I'll link to once I find it again.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. I took the liberty of linking to the resources you mentioned in the answer; I hope that's okay and that they're accurate (you had *Adventuring* rather than *Adventure* originally, for instance). You might want to make sure the checklist you're thinking of isn't the same one that's in the question. Anyway, thank you for participating and for helping strangers.

Comment: Thank you, and you're right, I forgot to click on it.  That's the one...My bad!

Answer (score 1):

Rules for creating a traveling show can also be found on pages 123-135 of [Rifts Black Market](https://palladium-store.com/1001/product/886-Rifts-Black-Market.html).

Comment: Hi mrbrandon!  Welcome to RPG.SE!  Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already, and check out the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) for more guidance.  Congratulations on your first post - it is clear, direct, answers the question, and includes a properly hyperlinked citation.  Well done!  We look forward to more contributions!  You may want to search on, or watch, the "rifts" and "palladium-system" tags, if that is your area of interest.